# JQuery send Ajax GET with Headers and open in new Window/Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending an AJAX GET request where some header parameters are passed. Not URL parameters but headers in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/myendpoint/ABCDE-12345",
         headers: { 'X-Auth-Token' : myTokenId},             
         type: "GET",
         success: function() { 

                  }
         });
```

This endpoint returns a file but it requires authentication via OAuth token passed into the headers of the request. 
When the request is returned I should display the returning file into a new Tab/Window of the browser. Is this possible?

Without authentication we can send the request in this way and it works:

```
window.open('http://localhost/myendpoint/ABCDE-12345', '_blank')
```

Comment: If you need result in new tab why send ajax ?

Comment: Because I need to pass "headers" into the request. Is there another way to pass headers into a GET/POST request without using $.Ajax?

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score 2):

For sure it is. You could use the new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and it's `res.blob()` method to retrieve a Blob, then `URL.createObjectURL` can be used to create a temporary URL to the file which the browser can resolve. You can then open that URL in a new tab

```js
fetch("http://localhost/myendpoint/ABCDE-12345", {
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token' : myTokenId },             
  method: "GET"
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank"));
```

Answer (score -2):

add thiss function to js :

```
      function submit_post_via_hidden_form(url, params) {
           var f = $("<form target='_blank' method='POST' style='display:none;'></form>").attr({
               action: url
           }).appendTo(document.body);

            for (var i in params) {
              if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                 $('<input type="hidden" />').attr({
                    name: i,
                    value: params[i]
                 }).appendTo(f);
              }
        }

        f.submit();

        f.remove();
    }
```

change your code to this :

```
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/myendpoint/ABCDE-12345",
     headers: { 'X-Auth-Token' : myTokenId},             
     type: "GET",
     success: function(e) { 
         submit_post_via_hidden_form("http://localhost/myendpoint/ABCDE-12345/preview.php", {'preview':e})
        }
     });
```

now create `preview.php`:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['preview'])){
        echo $_POST['preview'];
     }
?>
```

Comment: why a hidden form? I need to pass the authentication token into a header, why the form with POST and the ajax request with GET? Also, this is not opening into a new Tab/Window of the browser it just a redirect, so useless for me

Comment: authentication loaded on your ajax request and hidden form just for show result.

Comment: This not possible  this function create new tab, maybe your browser not standard or have  pop blocker.